# How to transform an android google maps standart polyline into blue circles?

Tags: android, google-maps-api-3, geometry, polyline

If you open up a google maps app on your phone, select any destination and set mode to "WALKING", the standart polyline transforms into blue little circles.

How do I achieve it programmatically?

I see a year old discussion here, but they are also clueless: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/maps/j9iEMmZ_oXI

Answer (score 0):

Seems there is no possibilities to do it with Google Maps API, but You can try to get directions and use `Overlay` like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2184239/6950238) answer of [mnish](https://stackoverflow.com/users/263481/mnish) and for drawing circles instead of solid line in

```
public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapv, boolean shadow){
    ...
}
```

you can use [that](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40729016/6950238) approach (do not pay attention to the fact that answer is about Mabpox - in both cases drawing on `Canvas` should be used) based on  [`setPathEffect()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Paint.html#setPathEffect(android.graphics.PathEffect)) method of `Paint` class (briefly for this You should create path for "circle stamp" (in pixels), which will repeated every "advance" (in pixels too)).