# Dotted circle route path like google map

Tags: android, google-maps, marker, polyline

### [image: Google map]

I want a Map UI like above dotted circle route path .I searched a lot through web and stack overflow i cant find any source.

I tried

- addCircle polyline but the circle is large when i zoom the camera to
     an extend in google map
- I don't know how google map implemented it either with marker or
  polyline

Provided help is appreciated rather than downvotes!!

thanks :-)

Comment: Take a look at my project here https://github.com/antoniocarlon/richmaps

Comment: map.addCircle(CircleOptions) or add overlayView to draw dished line using override onDraw on draw line with Paint.setPathEffect(new DashPathEffect(new float[] {10,20}, 0));

Comment: @Qamar could you send me the link or sample for canvas overlay view .I used addCircle UI is not good but while searching on web i came to know about overlay but i can't find a sample or link for it .thanks

Comment: add many circles or Polygon that take similar shape

Comment: addCircle does not look good if i zoom my map the circle get even bigger

Comment: You can extend `MapView` and override onDraw to draw stuff over map. Draw your stuff after super.onDraw. Just push too find solution. check out if this help you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Stroke Patterns](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-api/shapes#stroke_pattern) for polylines like this:

```
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    List<LatLng> sourcePoints = new ArrayList<>();
    sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(22.724526, 75.825979));
    sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(22.720165, 75.905953));
    sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(22.766649, 76.075773));
    sourcePoints.add(new LatLng(22.862032, 76.098302));

    PolylineOptions polyLineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
    polyLineOptions.addAll(sourcePoints);
    polyLineOptions.width(50f);
    polyLineOptions.color(Color.rgb(0, 178, 255));
    Polyline polyline = googleMap.addPolyline(polyLineOptions);

    List<PatternItem> pattern = Arrays.<PatternItem>asList(new Dot(), new Gap(10f));
    polyline.setPattern(pattern);

    CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(sourcePoints.get(2))
            .zoom(14)                   
            .build();
googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

}
```

to get result like that:

[image: Dotted path polyline]

Unfortunately it's impossible to draw bigger circles under smaller to achieve "bordered" circles path because of nonlinear dependency between [`Dot()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Dot) and [`Gap()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Gap) sizes.

Or you can draw whatever you want on [`MapVew`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/MapView) canvas via overriding `dispatchDraw()` of `MapView` like in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40729016/6950238) answer (it's about `MapBox` [`MapView`](https://www.mapbox.com/android-docs/api/map-sdk/5.0.2/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/maps/MapView.html), but approach is applicable for Google Maps `MapView` too).

Answer (score 0):

I think its overkill, but you can use some of Google APIs from https://console.developers.google.com/apis/library

and get path and make from them set of LatLngs, then draw them on googleMap just like normal marker, but with small round circle as icon.

To be honest, I am not sure what you want to achieve, I think simpler idea is to use origin and destination and open it in GoogleMaps Android App - do not reinvent the wheel.

Comment: i used the api and i have all the point i need to draw on google map

Comment: only thing is i want my UI to look like above pic i dont know whether google used maker or polyline to achieve this view

Comment: you can "make" additional latlngs between each 2 points for example points (x1,y1) and (x2,y2)  you can draw 'dotted' marker at coordinates ([x1+x2]/2, [y1+y2]/2) and so on.

Comment: i have all my point like you said the intermediate ([x1+x2]/2, [y1+y2]/2) point .My problem is if you gone throw google map direction dotted route i want to know if they used marker to represent the point or polyline to represent the points